# Getting HttpMessageNotReadableException after upgarding spring to 2.3.11RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, upgrade

**Previous Version:**
springCloudVersion = "Greenwich.RELEASE"
springBootVersion = "2.1.13.RELEASE"

**Upgraded Version:**
springCloudVersion = "Hoxton.SR3"
springBootVersion = "2.3.11.RELEASE"

**Spring Code:**

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "valuemodified", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<OutputResource> processRequest(@RequestBody String jsonString) {
```

**PostMan call:**
[image]

**Error After Upgrade:**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public TestController.processRequest(java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
```

**Things which I have tried:**

1. Tried using postmapping instead of request mapping.
2. Used different mediatypes
   But none worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before anyone wastes their time duplicating effort, this has also been raised as a Spring Boot issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26959

Comment: I have raised after raising it here. Tried so many things from there but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. We have a wrapper around request.

I still don't know what change happened between the two mentioned spring boot versions but reading servletRequest. parameterMap in CachingRequestWrapper solved the issue.

Something which I found here: [@RequestParam with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring Boot 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041700/requestparam-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-working-in)